# Python. Удалить повторяющиеся элементы в списке

Tags: python, списки

Я формирую список из строк определенного столбца таблицы xls. Некоторые элементы списка повторяются, нужно удалить повторяющиеся. 
Использовал следующий код:

```
import xlrd

excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./file.xls')

sheet_count = excel_data_file.nsheets

for sheetno in range(sheet_count):
    sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(sheetno)
    row_number = sheet.nrows

ind_lst = sheet.col_values(0)
name_lst = sheet.col_values(2)
c = []
f = open('result.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0, len(name_lst)):
    if name_lst[i] == 'test1':
        b = name_lst[i]
        c = ind_lst[i]

        def unique(items):
            found = set([])
            keep = []

            for item in items:
                if item not in found:
                    found.add(item)
                    keep.append(item)

            return keep

        m = unique(c)
        print(m)
        f.write(''.join(m) + '\n')

f.close()
```

Но использование функции ничего не дало. В файле result.txt есть повторяющиеся строчки.

Comment: m = list(set(c)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример данных в `ind_lst` и `name_lst` и какой сейчас результат выдает и какой нужен

Comment: Объявление функции unique лучше вынести из цикла for.